# Can the regulatory domain be configured on Cisco WAP571 devices?

Tags: cisco, ieee-802.11

I got 3 WAP571 and 2 WAP571E (outdoor AP). According to specs, all 5 AP's should work in a Single Point Management and allow seamless roaming. Yet, the two types of AP's do not speak to each other.
My research showed that the WAP571 are set to regulatory domain "de", whereas the WAP571E are set to "dj". "de" has another set of available channels than "dj". Therefore seamless roaming is not possible.
I have not found a way to change the regulatory domain in those Cisco devices, and also not found any documentation on this topic.
In other products (i.e. Ubiquity UniFi), the regulatory domain can be changed. 
Question: Is it true that on Cisco WAP571 devices, changing the regulatory domain is not possible?

https://community.cisco.com/t5/small-business-wireless/wap571-wrong-country-code-broadcasted/td-p/2930231
https://208.74.205.244/t5/small-business-wireless/wap571-is-there-anyway-to-change-country-code/td-p/3816695

Comment: For any WAP, you must buy the correct model for the area in which it is to be installed. Different WAPs are manufactured differently, depending on the regulations for the country. You will not be able to alter that.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin. I was afraid this is the problem. I already contacted the distributor. As a Swiss customer, I guess should get devices manufactured for Switzerland and not for Djibouti or Germany. Interestingly, changing the regulation country works fine on other AP's from other vendors. I wonder why Cisco has another approach here.

Comment: @Igrokit, Cisco "bakes" more code into silicon to improve performance/capabilities of their devices. Other vendors typically use commodity silicon and a general purpose CPU, this improves flexibility (if everything is programmable, then it is easy to change) at the cost of performance/capabilities. This is also part of why Cisco products cost more than other vendors.

Comment: @YLearn, Great that Cisco provides top hw/sw. Problem is on the whole value chain. Cisco would have to predict the need in each "regulatory domain" for production. Looks like there is a surplus of "dj" locked WAP571E devices. Distributors buy cheapest. The spects of a WAP locked into for "de" or "dj" is absolutely identical. No wonder they would buy the  probably cheaper "dj" version, even if the target country is "de" or "ch". Nobody cares, as long there is not a feature used that explicitly needs the regulatory domain be the same for all WAP devices used together.

Comment: @Igrokit, there are separate regulatory domains with differing regulations on which frequencies/power levels can be using within their jurisdictions. Some of those require that this not be configurable by the end user. Further, users who do not understand these regulations can find themselves in trouble if they don't configure this correctly. You simply need to be aware of what you are actually buying and not buy "the cheapest" similar (but not same) model number you find, and this is true with many things, not just Cisco APs as those differences in model number signify differences in devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, At the time of procurement, you need to determine the domain.